# Full HD playback on RPi4 with hardware acceleration

Tags: pi-4, video, streaming-video, gpu

I am the owner of **Raspberry Pi 4B** with **2GB RAM** and latest Raspbian OS.
I already did some basic testing with HTML5 FullHD video or with Youtube and 1080p video, but playback is jerky and definitely not smooth.
I tried legacy GL driver and also fake KMS with GPU memory is setup to 256MB. I tried different combinations but without success.

Is even possible to get what I want on RPi4?

My current *CHROMIUM_FLAGS* are:
`CHROMIUM_FLAGS="${CHROMIUM_FLAGS} --ignore-gpu-blacklist --enable-one-copy-rasterizer --enable-gpu-rasterization --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers --enable-checker-imaging --enable-quic --site-per-process --enable-tcp-fastopen --disable-features=MaterialDesignBookmarks --disable-gpu-compositing --enable-fast-unload --enable-experimental-canvas-features --enable-scroll-prediction --answers-in-suggest --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-args=enable_stagevideo_auto=0 --ppapi-flash-version= --max-tiles-for-interest-area=512 --num-raster-threads=4 --default-tile-height=512"`

*chrome://gpu* output:

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Flash: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
OpenGL: Enabled
Hardware Protected Video Decode: Unavailable
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
Skia Renderer: Enabled
Video Decode: Unavailable
Viz Display Compositor: Enabled
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
```

Comment: This is maybe chromium (or bandwidth) because even the model 1 boards will play an  (H.264) Youtube  video in full HD.